# How to click a same class or id 2 times and get different properties using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, click

Thanks in advance, my language is not good sorry if there any mistakes,

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){
    $('.content').fadeIn();
});
$('.clickable').click(function(){
    $('.content').fadeOut();
});
```

Is there any way to click same class 2 times and get different properties.

I already tried by hiding one class and when click it shows,
 Here the details,

```
<div class="show">show</div>
<div class="hide" style="display:none;">hide</div>

$('.show').click(function(){
    $('.content').fadeIn();
    $('.show').css("display","none");
    $('.hide').css("display","block");
});
$('.hide').click(function(){
    $('.content').fadeOut();
    $('.hide').css("display","none");
    $('.show').css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: Give more clear about what you want?,with your original HTML code

Comment: You can use toggle method. Here is a demo. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle

Answer (score 2):

Use [**fadeToggle**](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)

```js
$('#FadeToggle').click(function() {
  $('.content').fadeToggle();

  $(this).text(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="content">the content</p>
<button id="FadeToggle">Hide</button>
```

Comment: @cHaMs, awesome, glad the answer helped :-)

Comment: Yes it helped alot,  I have one more doubt can we change the style of that content when first click, and return normal style when second click

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.toggle`

Also you cannot toggle element on it's click. You can hide, but once hidden, you cannot click it.

```js
$("#btnToggle").on("click", function(){
  $(".content").toggle(300);
})
```

```css
.content{
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  border:2px solid gray;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"> This is a test div</div>
<button id="btnToggle">Toggle visibility</button>
```